# Why CQRS is called as MicroServices Design Pattern and Not Monolithic Design Pattern?

Tags: microservices, cqrs, monolithic

The CQRS pattern splits the application into two parts: the command side and the query side. The command side handles create, update, and delete requests. The query side runs the query part by using the read replicas.

This thing can be achieved in Monolithic architecture as well, there also we could have a write replica and read replica. Then Why this pattern is called as a Microservices Design Pattern.

Can somebody explain this and correct me if my understanding is wrong about it?

Comment: "Can anybody explain this?"  Yes - lots of people don't know what they are talking about.  CQRS is a pattern that has applications beyond "microservices".  See: https://web.archive.org/web/20101223100708/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/

Answer (score 0):

CQRS pattern solves the problem,

"How to implement a query that retrieves data from multiple services in a microservice architecture?"

[Read here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html)

API Composition pattern is a slower alternative to CQRS.

Answer (score 0):

CQRS is one of several application architecture patterns. It does not depend upon how the application is deployed.